# How to identify the name of the package?

Tags: software-center, package-management

Lets say I want to download the 'Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components' in the image below. What is the name of the package? is it 'gnome' or 'Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components' or ...?

[image]

Comment: I install Gnome in Ubuntu 13.10, what is your version?
These steps are to upgrade from the console http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10 Saludos

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the package name of a Software that you see it in Ubuntu Software Center (in this case "Full GNOME Desktop Environment"), you can use the following command in terminal:

```
$ apt-cache search "Full GNOME Desktop Environment"
gnome - Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components
```

So, the package name in this case is `gnome`.

To install it on a machine where you don't have an internet connection, you can use one method from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/321954/147044).